# How to return specific text from a file based on its pattern?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file with several lines and would like to output a single word from it.
e.g.

```
bla bla bla bla
WORD1 bla ldskjf sldfkj 0xksjdflksjflksjf
```

From this file, I would like to output only the word `0xksjdflksjflksjf`.
I am thinking of a command that would look for the line starting by `WORD1` and then, looking for a word starting by `0x` in this line.

I'm quite sure that `awk` or `sed` would allow me to do that.
I found a way to do it but it doesn't very "clean":

```
awk '/^WORD1/ {print $5}'
```

It works but is there a better (e.g. based on the word pattern instead of its place in the line) way to do it?

Comment: agree with @MarcoLucidi, also is the `0x....` substring always the same length or does it vary?

Comment: I think it is always the same

Comment: `grep -Po '^WORD1.*\W\K0x\w*'`

Comment: @Abelisto : I was not aware of the `\K`. Maybe you want to present this as answer? I think it is helpful.

Comment: @user1934428 It causes the regex engine to "keep" everything it had matched prior to the \K and not include it in the result. And it could be wrong answer because it returns only last ocurence of the desired word (if there are several `0x...` in the line)

Comment: Yes, I found this meanwhile. Perhaps the last occurance is fine for the OP; at least it matches his example. I find the \K idea cool and much leaner than an awk solution. That's why I would propose that you give this as answer, instead of a mere comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a file called 0x.txt with the following:

```
bla bla bla bla
WORD1 bla ldskjf sldfkj 0xksjdflksjflksjf
bla bla bla bla
WORD1 bla 0xksjdflksjflks ldskjf sldfkj
```

then:

```
awk '/^WORD1/ {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( match($i, /^0x/) ) print $i}' 0x.txt
```

will print what you need not depending on column number:

```
0xksjdflksjflksjf
0xksjdflksjflks
```

Answer (score 1):

And a `sed` version (using GNU sed):

The input file:

```
cat file
bla bla bla bla
WORD1 bla ldskjf sldfkj 0xksjdflksjflksjf
```

Command execution:

```
sed -nr /^WORD1/{'s/^(WORD1.+)(0x\w+)(.*$)/\2/p}' file
0xksjdflksjflksjf
```

Suppressing normal output (`-n`), find lines beginning with `WORD1`, substitute everything up to `0x` with nothing, then print the line.

Comment: How about `sed -nE '/^WORD1/s/^[^0]+(0x\w+).*$/\1/p' file`? (you already made your edit right as I posted the comment)

Comment: But you're right, I don't need the last capture group!

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by [@AlexZhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8545678/alex-zhu), but as an alternative without needing to iterate from `1` to `NF` using `match()` and then the `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` built-in variables set by `match()` along with `substr()`, e.g., using the same input file provided by @AlexZhu you would have:

```
awk '
    /^WORD1/ {
        match($0,/[ ]0x[^ ]+/)
        if (RLENGTH > -1)
            print substr ($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH)
    }
' file
0xksjdflksjflksjf
0xksjdflksjflks
```

The documentation for each of the functions are contained in [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions).